# American music vs the rest of the world

Tags: genre, live-music

Which non-US artist has made a huge impact in the world in terms of music sales?

We know Michael Jackson is among the names in American musicians.

Comment: Hi Maneza F8 and welcome to the site!  Stack Exchange is a little different from other websites --we're not really a forum for discussions, so open ended questions aren't a good fit here.  We're really looking primarily for questions that potentially have one, well-defined answer, not list questions.  For instance: "Which non-US rappers have appeared on the US Billboard music charts?"

Comment: Top all time selling artists include The Beatles, Led Zeppelin, Elton John, AC/DC, Pink Floyd... probably more Rest Of The World than US.

Comment: Elton john was on my mind when I was asking this question and artists like Adele, Ed Sheeran and the likes of Bob Marley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_music_artists)

1. The Beatles [UK] - 600m
2. Elvis Presley [US] - 600m
3. Michael Jackson [US] - 350m
4. Madonna [US] - 300m
5. Elton John [UK] - 300m
6. Led Zeppelin [UK] - 300m
7. Rihanna [Barbados] - 250m
8. Pink Floyd [UK] - 250m

Answer (score 2):

AC/DC has probably made the biggest impact that is not from the USA

Comment: Who is that? I never heard of AC/DC at all.

Comment: Check YouTube for them. If you like Hard Rock, you'll like them.  :)

Comment: ooh yeah I see they from Australia I see on wikipedia they are Huge.

Comment: Yeah, do you like 'em?  They are one of my favorites. Also try Ozzy Osbourne. He's from England.

Comment: Lol I am actually listening to them on youtube now its a nice music it will take time though to sink in but they are good.

Comment: My favorite album from AC/DC is 'Back In Black'. But they have a lot of good songs!

Comment: I will listen to it over the weekend, Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94910/discussion-between-skypaul-and-maneza-f8).